# What is the easiest way to change and play around with jdk code

Tags: java

I just wanted to play around with the jdk . Like changing the implementation of some algo in some utilities in java.util etc . I just tried copying Treemap to a new class but in the same package java.util . But when i try to use my copied class , I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

But i cant change the package also since Treemap is using some package access stuff from other classes in java.util .

***I jst told what i did . But please do tell me if there is an easier way to change some part of jdk implementation and use the modified code ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-Xbootclasspath/p:mydir` to load you classes into the bootstrap class loader in preference to the system classes. (`p` is prepend.)

If you want to make a copy of the classes instead of replace them, then they will need to be outside of the `java.` If it depends upon package-private access, then you'll need to copy the other classes to (or make them public in place with `-Xbootclasspath/p:`). package hierarchy.

Comment: Just about to add this but you beat me to it! I believe it's -Xbootclasspath. I use a separate Eclipse project called "jdkplay" and put any experimental JDK copied Java files into it, in the correct package obviously. Then on the run config I use the  switch: -Xbootclasspath/p:d:/projects/jdkplay/bin. It works a treat. Very handy for adding debugging/logging code and logic to Swing classes.